# Erro "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" em programa de if-else linguagem C

Tags: c, if, else, falha-de-segmentação

Saudações!

Sou iniciante em programação e encontrei esse problema em um código: Segmentation fault (core dumped), após dar entrada na primeira variável.

Esse é o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>

/*Elabore um algoritmo que permita a entrada de dois valores (x e y) e escreva como resultado o maior entre eles, usando apenas duas variaveis. */

int main()  
{  
     int x, y;  
    //inserindo e processando os numeros  
        printf("Digite um valor para x:\n", &x);  
        scanf("%d", x);  
        printf("Digite um valor para y:\n", &y);  
        scanf("%d", y);  
    //condicoes para aparecer o maior  
        if(x > y){  
            printf("%d\n", x);  
                }else{  
                    if (x == y)  
                        printf("OS NUMEROS SAO IGUAIS A %d",x);  
                            else  
                                printf("%d",y);  
                }  
}
```

Isso é o que aparece em relação ao que está errado, mas não consegui entender.

```
[lista03questao01.c 2021-08-21 23:33:48.604]  
,,lista03questao01.c: In function ‘main’:  
lista03questao01.c:11:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]  
   11 |         printf("Digite um valor para x:\n", &x);  
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lista03questao01.c:12:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but  
 argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   12 |         scanf("%d", x);
      |                ~^   ~
      |                 |   |
      |                 |   int
      |                 int *
lista03questao01.c:13:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
   13 |         printf("Digite um valor para y:\n", &y);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lista03questao01.c:14:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]  
   14 |         scanf("%d", y);         
      |                 ~^   ~
      |                  |   |
      |                  |   int
      |                  int *
```

Perdão se a dúvida for muito básica, tentei buscar em respostas a outras dúvidas, mas encontrei apenas para outros casos e não consegui adaptar ao meu. Agradeço muito a quem puder ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código tem alguns problemas:

- Primeiro problema: `printf("Digite um valor para x:\n", &x);`
  O símbolo `&` serve, nesse caso, para passar um endereço de memória, não teria problema passar um endereço de memória como argumento para uma função `printf` mas o principal problema nesse caso, é que a função não sabe o que fazer com esse argumento, pois não tenhum `%d` dentro da string do `printf` para ele poder ser usado, então o compilador exibe o primeiro e terceiro avisos.
- Segundo problema: `scanf("%d", x);`
  O `scanf` sim precisa de um endereço de memória para alterar o valor da variável, então nesse caso o compilador exibe o segundo e quarto avisos.

---

**Solução**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  
{
    int x, y;
    printf("Digite um valor para x:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Digite um valor para y:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    if(x > y)
        printf("%d\n", x);
    else
    {
        if (x == y)
            printf("OS NUMEROS SAO IGUAIS A %d\n", x);
        else
            printf("%d\n", y);
    }
}
```